# How to ignore nulls while unmarshalling a MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, bson, mongo-go

I would like to know if there's any approach that would allow me to ignore null types while unmarshalling a MongoDB document into a Go struct.

Right now I have some auto-generate Go structs, something like this:

```golang
type User struct {
  Name  string `bson:"name"`
  Email string `bson:"email"`
}
```

Changing the types declared in this struct is not an option, and here's the problem; in a MongoDB database, which I do not have total control, some of the documents have been inserted with null values were originally I was not expecting nulls. Something like this:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "email": null
}
```

As the string types declared inside my struct are not pointers, they can't receive a `nil` value, so whenever I try to unmarshall this document in my struct, it returns an error.

Preventing the insertion of this kind of document into the database would be the ideal solution, but for my use case, ignoring the null values would also be acceptable. So after unmarshalling the document my User instance would look like this

```golang
User {
  Name:  "John Doe",
  Email: "",
}
```

I'm trying to find, either some annotation flag, or an option that could be passed to the method `Find`/`FindOne`, or maybe even a query parameter to prevent returning any field containing null values from the database. Without any success until now.

Are there any built-in solutions in the mongo-go-driver for this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the current bson codecs do not support encoding / decoding `string` into / from `null`.

One way to handle this is to create a custom decoder for `string` type in which we handle `null` values: we just use the empty string (and more importantly don't report error).

Custom decoders are described by the type [`bsoncodec.ValueDecoder`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsoncodec#ValueDecoder). They can be registered at a [`bsoncodec.Registry`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsoncodec#Registry), using a [`bsoncodec.RegistryBuilder`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsoncodec#RegistryBuilder) for example.

Registries can be set / applied at multiple levels, even to a whole [`mongo.Client`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Client), or to a [`mongo.Database`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database) or just to a [`mongo.Collection`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection), when acquiring them, as part of their options, e.g. [`options.ClientOptions.SetRegistry()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#ClientOptions.SetRegistry).

First let's see how we can do this for `string`, and next we'll see how to improve / generalize the solution to any type.

### 1. Handling `null` strings

First things first, let's create a custom string decoder that can turn a `null` into a(n empty) string:

```
import (
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsoncodec"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsonrw"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsontype"
)

type nullawareStrDecoder struct{}

func (nullawareStrDecoder) DecodeValue(dctx bsoncodec.DecodeContext, vr bsonrw.ValueReader, val reflect.Value) error {
    if !val.CanSet() || val.Kind() != reflect.String {
        return errors.New("bad type or not settable")
    }
    var str string
    var err error
    switch vr.Type() {
    case bsontype.String:
        if str, err = vr.ReadString(); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    case bsontype.Null: // THIS IS THE MISSING PIECE TO HANDLE NULL!
        if err = vr.ReadNull(); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot decode %v into a string type", vr.Type())
    }

    val.SetString(str)
    return nil
}
```

OK, and now let's see how to utilize this custom string decoder to a `mongo.Client`:

```
clientOpts := options.Client().
    ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/").
    SetRegistry(
        bson.NewRegistryBuilder().
            RegisterDecoder(reflect.TypeOf(""), nullawareStrDecoder{}).
            Build(),
    )
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
```

From now on, using this `client`, whenever you decode results into `string` values, this registered `nullawareStrDecoder` decoder will be called to handle the conversion, which accepts bson `null` values and sets the Go empty string `""`.

But we can do better... Read on...

### 2. Handling `null` values of any type: "type-neutral" null-aware decoder

One way would be to create a separate, custom decoder and register it for each type we wish to handle. That seems to be a lot of work.

What we may (and should) do instead is create a single, "type-neutral" custom decoder which handles just `null`s, and if the BSON value is not `null`, should call the default decoder to handle the non-`null` value.

This is surprisingly simple:

```
type nullawareDecoder struct {
    defDecoder bsoncodec.ValueDecoder
    zeroValue  reflect.Value
}

func (d *nullawareDecoder) DecodeValue(dctx bsoncodec.DecodeContext, vr bsonrw.ValueReader, val reflect.Value) error {
    if vr.Type() != bsontype.Null {
        return d.defDecoder.DecodeValue(dctx, vr, val)
    }

    if !val.CanSet() {
        return errors.New("value not settable")
    }
    if err := vr.ReadNull(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Set the zero value of val's type:
    val.Set(d.zeroValue)
    return nil
}
```

We just have to figure out what to use for `nullawareDecoder.defDecoder`. For this we may use the default registry: [`bson.DefaultRegistry`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#DefaultRegistry), we may lookup the default decoder for individual types. Cool.

So what we do now is register a value of our `nullawareDecoder` for all types we want to handle `null`s for. It's not that hard. We just list the types (or values of those types) we want this for, and we can take care of all with a simple loop:

```
customValues := []interface{}{
    "",       // string
    int(0),   // int
    int32(0), // int32
}

rb := bson.NewRegistryBuilder()
for _, v := range customValues {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    defDecoder, err := bson.DefaultRegistry.LookupDecoder(t)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rb.RegisterDecoder(t, &nullawareDecoder{defDecoder, reflect.Zero(t)})
}

clientOpts := options.Client().
    ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/").
    SetRegistry(rb.Build())
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
```

In the example above I registered null-aware decoders for `string`, `int` and `int32`, but you may extend this list to your liking, just add values of the desired types to the `customValues` slice above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you just give me another guidance? If I want the same behavior for other types, such as int and float, how should I proceed?

Comment: @Andrew Please see edited answer. I showed how to create a "type-neutral" null-aware decoder, and included an example how to register it for multiple types.

Comment: Awesome - I wish I had seen this a few months ago - thanks @icza

Comment: Absolutely beautiful answer. Actually also led to me using go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/* instead of github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/*

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the operator [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#exists) and [Query for Null or Missing Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#query-for-null-or-missing-fields) for a detail explanation.

In the mongo-go-driver, you can try below query:

The email => nil query **matches documents** that either contains the **email field** whose value is ***nil*** or that ***do not contain the email field***.

```
cursor, err := coll.Find(
   context.Background(),
   bson.D{
      {"email", nil},
})
```

You have to just add the `$ne` operator in the above query to get the records that do not have the field email or do not have the value `nil` in email. For more details about the operator [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/index.html#ne)

Comment: That's not really what I'm trying to do. I'm not trying to query elements by the existence or not of `null` values, I'm trying to parse a document that may contain null values into a struct that won't accept `nil` values.

Answer (score 1):

If you know ahead of time which fields could potentially be null in your mongoDB records, you can use pointers in your structs instead:

```
type User struct {
  Name  string `bson:"name"` // Will still fail to decode if null in Mongo
  Email *string `bson:"email"` // Will be nil in go if null in Mongo
}
```

Just remember that now you'll need to code more defensively around anything that uses this value after decoding from mongo, eg:

```
var reliableVal string
if User.Email != nil {
    reliableVal = *user.Email
} else {
    reliableVal = ""
}
```