# Custom BSON marshal and unmarshal using mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, protocol-buffers, marshalling, bson

I have a struct field like this below. I also store raw protobuf of the same struct in db. Now every time fetch or save data to mongo. I have to update `ReallyBigRaw`, from the proto when I want to save to DB and when fetch I have to unmarshal `ReallyBigRaw` to `ReallyBigObj` to give out responses. Is there a way I can implement some interface or provide some callback functions so that the mongo driver does this automatically before saving or fetching data from DB.

Also, I am using the offical golang mongo driver not `mgo`, I have read some answers where can be done in `mgo` golang library.

```golang
import (
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"

    proto "github.com/dinesh/api/go"
)

type ReallyBig struct {
    ID           string                 `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    DraftID      string                 `bson:"draft_id,omitempty"`
// Marshaled ReallyBigObj proto to map[string]interface{} stored in DB
    ReallyBigRaw map[string]interface{} `bson:"raw,omitempty"`
    ReallyBigObj *proto.ReallyBig       `bson:"-"`
    CreatedAt    primitive.DateTime     `bson:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt    primitive.DateTime     `bson:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}

func (r *ReallyBig) GetProto() (*proto.ReallyBig, error) {
    if r.ReallyBigObj != nil {
        return r.ReallyBigObj, nil
    }
    Obj, err := getProto(r.ReallyBigRaw)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    r.ReallyBigObj = Obj
    return r.ReallyBigObj, nil
}

func getRaw(r *proto.ReallyBig) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    m := jsonpb.Marshaler{}
    b := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{})

    // marshals proto to json format
    err := m.Marshal(b, r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var raw map[string]interface{}
    // unmarshal the raw data to an interface
    err = json.Unmarshal(b.Bytes(), &raw)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return raw, nil
}

func getProto(raw map[string]interface{}) (*proto.ReallyBig, error) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(raw)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    u := jsonpb.Unmarshaler{}
    var reallyBigProto proto.ReallyBig
    err = u.Unmarshal(bytes.NewReader(b), &recipeProto)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &reallyBigProto, nil
}
```

Comment: `bson.Marshaler` and `bson.Unmarshaler` work with the official driver too. Another way is using coders and decoders, for an example see [How to ignore nulls while unmarshalling a MongoDB document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984435/how-to-ignore-nulls-while-unmarshalling-a-mongodb-document/58985629#58985629)

Comment: Thanks a ton. The example talks about handling types. But in my case I just need the raw field to be updated with the current proto state and then let mongo take care of marshaling to DB and when unmarshaling from DB, just fill proto from that raw. 

An example would really help.

Comment: @icza i was able to implement marshaler and unmarshaler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented the `Marshaler` and `Unmarshaler` interface. Since mongo driver calls `MarshalBSON` and `UnmarshalBSON` if the type implements `Marshaler` and `Unmarshaler` we also end up in infinite loop. To avoid that we create a Alias of the `type`. Alias in `Golang` inherit only the fields not the methods so we end up calling normal `bson.Marshal` and `bson.Unmarshal`

```golang
func (r *ReallyBig) MarshalBSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type ReallyBigAlias ReallyBig
    reallyBigRaw, err := getRaw(r.ReallyBigObj)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    r.ReallyBigRaw = reallyBigRaw
    return bson.Marshal((*ReallyBigAlias)(r))
}

func (r *ReallyBig) UnmarshalBSON(data []byte) error {
    type ReallyBigAlias ReallyBig
    err := bson.Unmarshal(data, (*ReallyBigAlias)(r))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    reallyBigProto, err := getProto(r.ReallyBigRaw)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    r.ReallyBigObj = reallyBigProto
    return nil
}
```