# Decode in BSON, an interface which is implemented by a private structure

Tags: mongodb, go, crud, bson, mongo-go

I am trying to do a basic TODO list application in Go. I am creating the CRUD operations on my cluster from mongodb atlas. But I have a problem decoding BSON objects. For my model I use a struct which is unimported but it implements a interface which is used in the repo. When trying to read from database I get this error:

> panic: no decoder found for interfaces.IToDoItem

I know I should somehow implement a decoder for my interface but can not realize how to do it, without exporting my main struct from model. That would also mean I won't have a privacy in the model and the items in the model can be accessed in any mode all around the program, a thing which I think is wrong.

Here is my code:

model.go

```
type toDoItem struct{
    ItemId      int             `bson:"itemId,omitempty"`
    Title       string          `bson:"title,omitempty"`
    Description string          `bson:"description,omitempty"`
}

func New(itemId int,title string,description string) interfaces.IToDoItem {
    return toDoItem{
        ItemId:      itemId,
        Title:       title,
        Description: description,
    }
}

func (item toDoItem)GetItemId()int{
    return item.ItemId
}

func (item toDoItem)GetTitle()string{
    return item.Title
}

func (item toDoItem)GetDescription()string{
    return item.Description
}
```

Interface

```
type IToDoItem interface {
    GetItemId() int
    GetTitle() string
    GetDescription() string
}
```

repo function

```
func (r *Repository)GetAll() []interfaces.IToDoItem{
    cursor, err := r.collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{})
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    defer cursor.Close(context.Background())

    var allItems []interfaces.IToDoItem

    for cursor.Next(context.Background()){
        var result interfaces.IToDoItem
        err := cursor.Decode(&result)
        if err!= nil{
            panic(err)
        }
        allItems = append(allItems[:],result)
    }
    fmt.Println(allItems)
    return []interfaces.IToDoItem{}
}
```

For now it does not return anything because I want to resolve the issues at the repo level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces are not concrete types, there may be multiple (any number of) types implementing it. The driver rightfully doesn't know how to instantiate it.

Fields of `toDoItem` are exported, there is no reason to make `toDoItem` itself unexported. Just export it and use a slice of `[]ToDoItem` (or `[]*ToDoItem`), and all your problems go away.

Also note that there is a [`Cursor.All()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.All) method to get all results, so you don't have to iterate over the documents and call [`Cursor.Decode()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.Decode) for each.

If you'd ever need to register custom decoders, check out this answer how to do it:

[How to ignore nulls while unmarshalling a MongoDB document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984435/how-to-ignore-nulls-while-unmarshalling-a-mongodb-document/58985629#58985629)

Comment: So i should not use a interface for the model at all?

Comment: @Stefan Easier for everyone to use structs.

Comment: Huh, i thought that i should leave the model unexported to simulate the private fields from OOP.